# Does WPF DatePicker allow you to specify a time zone?

Tags: .net, wpftoolkit

I'm using the WPF Toolkit's DatePicker to select a date.  We would like to set DateTime that we get after selecting a date to be at the end of the selected date.  Since we are converting the to UTC time we need to be able to specify the user's time zone.  Since the tool is running on our machine's we cannot use the current machine's local time.

When selecting a date in the DatePicker is it possible to specify the time zone the date corresponds to?

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you want to convert the DateTime from local time to UTC, all you need to do is call:

```
((DateTime) selectedTime).ToUniversalTime();
```

Make sure to read up on the caveats of this method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx